# Java/Android - Can not init socket (bind) bind failed : eaddrnotavail - in Emulator

Tags: java, android, sockets

Is this the emulator's problem because port 4442 could be reserved for the OS or has it got something to do with my code?

The error looks like http://prntscr.com/2sxqqs

I have included this line in my manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

I am initializing my socket and InetAddress inside the onCreate method , but they are privately declared outside any method. The socket is still null you know , the port is 4442 and the inetaddress to get by name is http://prntscr.com/2sxr2s

I am trying to send UDP packets over Lan. If you are interested , this is how the error-prone code looks like :

```
private byte[] buf = new byte[1];

private DatagramPacket p;

private int port = 4442;
private InetAddress ip; 
private DatagramSocket s;


 try {//////INSIDE ONCREATE
            ip = InetAddress.getByName(Dataholder.ip);
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {}

        try {
            s = new DatagramSocket(port , ip);
        } catch (SocketException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

private void sendPacket(int num){
     buf = Integer.toString(num).getBytes();
     p = new DatagramPacket(buf , buf.length, ip,port);  
     if(s !=null){
     try {
        s.send(p);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.i(tag, e.getMessage());
    }
    }else{
        Log.i(tag, "s=null");//This one prints out :/
    }
 }
```